# How to disable edit on a .msi file properties?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I'm completely new to Wix tools so I have no idea how to change this. I used Wix Toolset from a Visual Studio 2017 Extension to build a .msi file out of my C# project. The msi file is generated but the problem is I can change the properties of the file (Such as Title, Comments, Authors, etc.). The manufacturer attribute does not appear on details too. I have looked at the [documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) and tried like adding 'ReadOnly' attribute on the Package element but it does nothing.

How do I disable edit on the msi file properties?

**Product.wxs (Product element):**

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Program Name" Language="1033" Version="!(bind.FileVersion.ProgramDLL)" Manufacturer="Company Name" UpgradeCode="random GUID">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Description="$(var.ProductName) Setup" Comments="$(var.ProductName) is a product of Company Name" Manufacturer="Company Name" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="Programname.License.rtf" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Banner.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Welcome.bmp" />
<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="icon.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
<MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades='yes' Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of $(var.ProductName) is already installed. Setup will now exit." />

<Property Id='INSTALLFOLDER'>
  <RegistrySearch Id='R_InstallDir' Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\Program\ProgramName' Name='InstallDir' Type='raw' />
</Property>

<Condition Message="Install Folder of Program Name not found">INSTALLFOLDER</Condition>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Program_Setup" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="Cmp" />
  <ComponentRef Id="License" />
        <ComponentRef Id="DokuXSD" />
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

Comment: You can't (other than file permissions on the file in a location). But if you sign it and users understand that it should be signed _by you_, they _might_ notice when given an edited msi because it won't be signed _by you_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Corporate Advantages of MSI***: A key aspect of MSI - possibly one of the most important things that has given it corporate approval and use - is the fact that **MSI is an open format**. There are several other such [key corporate advantages for MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260) centering around **`transparency`**, **`customizability`**, **`reliable silent running`** and **`remote management`**.

***The Open MSI File Format***: I have this answer from before on the subject: [How to protect MSI against modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969925/how-to-protect-msi-against-modification/56970435#56970435). I am not sure if it is a 100% match to what you are asking, but maybe give it a quick read.

***MST - Transforms***: MSI (Windows Installer) has a feature called [transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/about-transforms)  (**`*.mst`** files) which is a built-in way to modify your MSI using an external file to do so - hence allowing corporate adaptation of your MSI without changing the actual MSI. In other words: users are intended to be able to customize your MSI for corporate use (using a dedicated, additional file).

***In Summary***: Don't worry that the fields can be changed, but consider signing your MSI with your own certificate to prevent your release files being tampered with in transit to your customer. Also: crucially do check your setup for **malware** and maybe update your **license agreement** to include a phrase that the setup was malware checked at the time of release, and that it is malware free **`"to the best of your knowledge"`**. The **`legalese`** here is not my expertise. Do check well as signing a setup that contains malware is proof positive that you delivered the malware :-) (until people hack signatures successfully too).

---

***Links***:

- Just for the record, some tools to view and modify MSI files: [How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546)