# How can i generate windows certificate so my msi doesn't shows warning to users

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-installer, exe

I am new to windows development. I packed my project into a msi setup to install on other systems but when I open the msi in any system it shows a warning as attached [image]. How can I remove this warning?

Comment: Maybe have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835413/4181058

Answer (score 1):

> ***Note***: Be sure to check if your organization already has an EV-level certificate? Just a few emails or phone calls might be wise before trying to research the purchase process?

---

> ***Trust & Reputation***: What you really need is an [**EV code-signing certificate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate). Microsoft's [SmartScreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SmartScreen) feature
>   in Windows (which is what you see with that blue prompt) is a
>   **reputation-based system** where unknown binaries are flagged as unsafe until they are validated safe by users in actual use.

[***Virustotal.com***](https://www.virustotal.com/): An [EV code-signing certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) *`"buys trust outright"`* - interesting concept - and should allow your users to not see such a prompt even for brand new binaries. Make sure to check all your binaries using [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com) though, as many malware-scanner detections can trigger a resurged smartscreen warning for any binary - which is what it is for ([*`signed malware is still malware`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969925/how-to-protect-msi-against-modification/56970435#56970435)).

***False Positives***: False positives for malware is a huge problem since **you** have to deal with it and solve it, and you can't just tell your users to rebuild their PC and try again.

> ***Moral***: The moral of the story is to use [Virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/) to test for both malware and false positives in your binaries and files for distribution, and to use an EV-level certificate for serious software distribution to get trust for your binaries outright (without delay). **An EV-level certificate is not a silver bullet**. Problems can still be seen. Trust can be lost too, not just gained (trust... hard to earn, easy to lose).

---

***Tip***: A properly signed MSI will also show up with the correct name in the UAC prompt: [Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer/) (see screen shot and then the answer a bit down the page).

---

***The Far Side Perspective***: *`"Be sure that your setup is malware free or an applied digital certificate is proof positive that you delivered the malware"`* ([until that is hackable too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24010770/129130)) :-)

We do our best.

---

***Link***:

- **[How to protect MSI against modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969925/how-to-protect-msi-against-modification/56970435#56970435)** (on malware and false positives - **recommended**)
- [How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018/50414337#50414337)
- [How to pass the Windows Defender SmartScreen Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806909/how-to-pass-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-protection/48835413#48835413)